# ant deployCode is running tests and succeeded but not deploying any thing

Tags: ant

ant deployCode is running tests and succeeded but not deploying any thing

**build.xml**

```
<target name="deployCode">
      <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" directory, running the tests for just 1 class -->
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests" deployRoot="ToDeploy">
         <runTest>OpportunityTest</runTest>
      </sf:deploy>
    </target>
```

I have contents in ToDeploy directory. any issues you could see? my user has all the required permissions but not deploying any thing.

Comment: What contents do you have in the "ToDeploy" directory? Does the `OpportunityTest` test class provide at least 75% coverage for all the other triggers and classes being deployed?

Comment: Daniel, I only have opportunitytrigger and it's covered by 95%

Comment: Are you using the same credentials in your ant script deployment as you're using to verify the deployment? (in other words, deploying to a different org than you're looking for results in)

Comment: i could see the deployment happening on the server, but at the end it says deployment succeeded but not deploying any thing

Comment: ant deployCodeNoTestLevelSpecified
Buildfile: /Users/vkatragadda/Documents/Vamsi/build.xml
deployCodeNoTestLevelSpecified:
[sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
[sf:deploy] Request ID for the current deploy task: 0Af8A0000025mYsSAI
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Succeeded
[sf:deploy] *********** DEPLOYMENT SUCCEEDED ***********
[sf:deploy] Finished request 0Af8A0000025mYsSAI successfully.

Comment: Try pulling the [DeployResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deployresult.htm?search_text=numberComponentsDeployed) using the 0Af8A0000025mYsSAI. This will tell you more about what happened.  In particular, you want to check that the numberComponentsDeployed is as expected. I'm not sure how to check this with the ant based tool. If you need, I've made a free tool that can check it based on the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Classes folder and include all your classes in that folder which should roll to your main folder. That should do the magic.